# Reflection coefficient for acoustic waves for normal incidence

Tags: optics, waves, acoustics, harmonic-oscillator, superposition

Suppose I have two mediums separated by a boundary at $x=0$. A wave, travelling from left to right, would get partly reflected and partly transmitted.

Left of the medium, I can write the total displacement as :

$$y_l=A\sin(\omega t-k_1x)+A'\sin(k_1x+\omega t)$$

Right of the medium, the displacement would be :

$$y_r=A''\sin(\omega t-k_2x)$$

In my book, the necessary boundary conditions are :

$$y_l(x=0)=y_r(x=0)$$
$$\frac{\partial y_l}{\partial x}(x=0)=\frac{\partial y_r}{\partial x}(x=0)$$

Using these, I get the two relations :

$$A+A'=A''$$
$$k_1(A-A')=k_2A''$$

Using this, my book defines the reflection coefficient as :

$$\frac{A'}{A}=\frac{k_1-k_2}{k_1+k_2}$$

For example, if medium $2$ is denser then, we can say $k_1<k_2$

In this case, if we assume $A>0$, then we can say $A'<0$.

Thus the reflected wave becomes : $y=A'\sin(k_1x+\omega t)=-|A'|\sin(k_1x+\omega t)=|A'|\sin(k_1x+\omega t+\pi)$.

This is interpreted as a phase change of $\pi$ between the reflected and the incident rays.

However, I could have done the derivation, by taking the argument of the waves traveling to the right as $kx-\omega t$ instead of the other way around. In this case, we would have :

$$y_l=A\sin(k_1x-\omega t)+A'\sin(k_1x+\omega t)$$
$$y_r=A''\sin(k_2x-\omega t)$$

In this case, we would get the reflection coefficient as :

$$\frac{A'}{A}=\frac{k_2-k_1}{k_1+k_2}$$

In this case, if $k_2>k_1$, if $A>0$, then $A'>0$ too.

However, if we write the incident and reflected waves at $x=0$, we'll find :
$$y_r=A'\sin(\omega t)$$
$$y_i=A\sin(-\omega t)=A\sin(\omega t-\pi)$$

Again we find that our reflected wave has a $\pi$ phase difference relative to the incident wave at the boundary.

In general our incident wave becomes : $y_i=A\sin(\omega t-k_1x+\pi)$

However, my definition of the reflection coefficient has now changed.

Is this second analysis acceptable? In most books, I've seen the $\omega t-kx$ form being used. Is there any special reason for using that form? I know that these forms are equivalent, but do most problems become easier or something when we use the previous form?

Comment: If you do this, the transmited wave will have a phase shift of 180 degrees relative to the incident wave. Is this what happens in reality?

Comment: Think of the phase velocity for the incident and reflective wave.

Comment: @nasu I don't see how transmitted wave is 180 out of phase, as both transmitted and incident has argument kx-wt

Comment: The incident has wt-kx according to your equations.

Comment: @nasu yeah but that is the first part. In the second part I've changed that for both transmitted and incident waves.